# Xerox Work center JCL syntax error/ Printing error (016-749)

Tags: 12.04, printing, syntax, xerox

Its long since Xerox workcenter 5225 is not working with my ubuntu 32 bit. The new error i am receiving is that says `JCL syntax error`. Still gnome in ubuntu tells me printing is successful but it actually gives error. Such things have been [reported on MAC](http://www.mactalk.com.au/14/55542-cannot-print-xerox-docucentre-work.html) as well. When i looked through trouble shooting manual this [error code (016-749)](http://www.manualslib.com/manual/195613/Xerox-Workcentre-M24.html?page=429) says

> Code (016-749)
>   Cause - A JCL command syntax error occurred
>
> remedy- Confirm the print settings, **or correct the JCL command.**

How to correct JCL command? I know nothing about it.

Comment: Please see this [Link](http://www.manualslib.com/manual/195613/Xerox-Workcentre-M24.html?page=429)

Comment: got the same on 5230 machine from kubuntu 12.10. seems xerox provided a wrong driver.
Xerox 5675 and docucolor 252 both work fine from the same computer box.